# how to fetch the records from database based on time in php

Tags: php, mysql

I fetched records from database , The list should be sorted by time. The latest appointment request should be at the top. Now it is sorted by File Number. 
    here is my code.....i want to display recent records first based on time,for example if i add 2 records today means these two records should be in first based on time.......

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />
</head>
<?php
    include_once 'config.php';
    $menu_name = 'patient'; 
    $_SESSION['menu']= $menu_name;  
    if(isset($_REQUEST['id']) && $_REQUEST['id']!='')
    {
        if(isset($_REQUEST['act']) && $_REQUEST['act']!='')
        {
            if($_REQUEST['act']=='r')
            {
                $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
                $deleteCondition = " id_patient='".$id."'";
                $deleted=$db->delete('patients',$deleteCondition);
                header("Location: appointments.php?m=r");
            }
        }
    }
   echo $query="SELECT p.*,u.fileno FROM patients AS p,users AS u WHERE p.status='a' AND p.users_id_user=u.id_user";
    $resultPatient=$db->select($query);
    $msgConfirmDelete ="Do you really want to delete this Patient ?";
    include_once 'header.php';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var msgDelete = '<?php echo $msgConfirmDelete; ?>';

 function confirmDelete()
 {
 if (confirm(msgDelete))
 {
 return true;
 }
 else
 {
 return false;
 }
 }
 </script> 
<!-- Sidebar begins -->
<div id="sidebar">

    <!-- Left Main menu begins -->
        <?php include_once 'menu.php'; ?>
    <!-- Left Main menu ends -->


    <!-- Secondary nav --> 
    <div class="secNav">
        <div class="secWrapper">
            <!--div class="secTop">
            </div-->
            <!--div class="divider"></div-->
            <div id="general">
                <div id="general" style="display: block;" class="active">
                <ul class="subNav">
                    <li><a href="add_appointment.php" title=""><span class="icos-images2"></span>Add Appointment</a></li>
                    <li class="activeli"><a href="appointments.php" title="" class="this"><span class="icos-images2"></span>View/Edit Appointments</a></li>
                    <li><a href="appointments_history.php" title=""><span class="icos-images2"></span>Appointments History</a></li>
                    <li><a href="reminder_settings.php" title=""><span class="icos-images2"></span>View/Edit Reminder Settings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="add_reminder_settings.php" title=""><span class="icos-images2"></span>Add Reminder Settings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="medicine_reminder_settings.php" title=""><span class="icos-images2"></span>View/Edit Medicine Reminder Settings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="add_medicine_reminder_settings.php" title=""><span class="icos-images2"></span>Add Medicine Reminder Settings</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>   
            </div> 
       </div> 
       <div class="clear"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- Sidebar ends -->


<!-- Content begins -->
<div id="content">
    <div class="contentTop">
        <span class="pageTitle"><span class="icon-screen"></span>View Appointments</span>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Breadcrumbs line -->
    <div class="breadLine">
        <div class="bc">
            <ul id="breadcrumbs" class="breadcrumbs">
                <li><a href="index.php">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="appointments.php">Appointments</a></li>
                <li class="current"><a href="#" title="">View Appointments</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Main content -->
    <div class="wrapper">


        <div class="fluid">
            <?php if(isset($_GET['m'])&&$_GET['m']=="a"){?>
           <div class="nNote nSuccess">
          <p>Appointment Added Successfully !</p>
          </div>
           <?php  }
           if(isset($_GET['m'])&&$_GET['m']=="d"){?>
           <div class="nNote nSuccess">
          <p>Appointment Status Changed Successfully !</p>
          </div>
          <?php  }
           if(isset($_GET['m'])&&$_GET['m']=="r"){?>
           <div class="nNote nSuccess">
          <p>Appointment Deleted Successfully !</p>
          </div>
          <?php  }
           if(isset($_GET['m'])&&$_GET['m']=="re"){?>
           <div class="nNote nSuccess">
          <p>Reminder Sent Successfully !</p>
          </div>
          <?php } 
           if(isset($_GET['m'])&&$_GET['m']=="u"){?>
           <div class="nNote nSuccess">
          <p>Appointment Updated Successfully !</p>
          </div>
          <?php } ?>
        <div class="widget">
            <div class="whead"><h6>View Appointment Information</h6><div class="clear"></div></div>
            <div id="dyn2" class="shownpars">
                <a class="tOptions act" title="Options"><img src="images/icons/options.png" alt="" /></a>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dTable">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Sl. No.<span class="sorting" style="display: block;"></span></th>
                <th>File No</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th width="80">Action</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                $sl=0;
                $req_date='';   
                if($resultPatient && count($resultPatient)>0)
                foreach($resultPatient as $patient)
                {
                    $sl+=1;                    
                    $req_date=date('d F Y', strtotime($patient['date']));
                ?>
                    <tr class="gradeX">
                    <td class="center"><?php echo $sl;?></td>
                    <td class="center"><?php echo $patient['fileno'];?></td>
                    <td class="center"><?php echo $patient['name'];?></td>
                    <td class="center"><?php echo $patient['email'];?></td>
                    <td class="center"><?php echo $patient['age'];?></td>
                    <td class="center"><?php echo strtoupper($patient['gender']);?></td>
                    <td class="center"><?php echo $patient['phone'];?></td>
                    <td class="center"><?php echo $req_date;?></td>
                    <td class="center"><?php echo $patient['time'];?></td>
                    <td class="tableActs">
                    <a href="edit_appointment.php?id=<?php echo $patient['id_patient'];?>" class="tablectrl_small <?php if($patient['confirm_status']=='c') echo 'bGreen'; else echo 'bDefault';?> tipS" title="Edit"><span class="iconb" data-icon="&#xe1db;"></span></a>
                    <a onclick="return confirmDelete();" href="appointments.php?id=<?php echo $patient['id_patient'];?>&act=r" class="tablectrl_small bDefault tipS" title="Delete"><span class="iconb" data-icon="&#xe136;"></span></a>
                    <a href="solveAppointments.php?id=<?php echo $patient['id_patient'];?>" class="lightbox tablectrl_small bDefault tipS" title="Status"><span class="iconb" data-icon="&#xe047;"></span></a>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php }?>                
                </tbody>
                </table> 
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div> 
        </div> 

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Main content ends -->

</div>
<!-- Content ends -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [orderby](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) for this purpose like

```
$query="SELECT p.*,u.fileno FROM patients AS p,users AS u WHERE p.status='a' AND p.users_id_user=u.id_user order by time DSC";
```

Comment: change asc or dsc according to your requirments

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="SELECT p.*,u.fileno FROM patients AS p,users AS u WHERE p.status='a' AND p.users_id_user=u.id_user order by p.time DESC";
```

Comment: @Arun change type to timestamp. and make default to "current timestamp"

Answer (score 0):

**Order By DESC**

Should work for you.

```
SELECT p.*,u.fileno FROM patients AS p,users AS u WHERE p.status='a' AND p.users_id_user=u.id_user order by time desc
```

using `ASC` will give it in **Ascending** order and DESC will give it in **Descending order**

Comment: @Arun This is showing the most recent inserted record. **assuming the column `TIME` is the time you inserted the record**

Comment: now i inserted one record but it is not showing top

Comment: @Arun is the column **`TIME`** the time when you inserted the row? If it is, Can you please show me how you inserted. Show me the `insert` query

Comment: in database structure time they took varchar field

Comment: @Arun Change it to TIME instead of varchar